# Why does Owl Carousel exceed my stylesheet ?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I've implemented Owl Carousel in Wordpress. I use Bootstrap so all my website is made from col and rows but when I put my code from Owl Carousel it breaks my stylesheet and set my page to 3000px width wide.

Here is the code

Does anyone have experienced the same issue ?

Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
          $(".slider1").owlCarousel({
            center: true,
            items:2,
            autowidth: true,
            loop:false,
            margin:10,
            responsive:{
              600:{
                items:4
              }
            }
          });
        });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="slider">

<?php
$args = array(
  'category_name' => 'test',
  'posts_per_page' => 2,
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="slider1">
      <?php  while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post();?>

        <div class="slide">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail('slider'); ?>
        </div>

        <?php
      endwhile;
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<? endif; ?>
</section>
```

Comment: Give us the rendered html please, not your PHP. And is there any more CSS that's relevant to these sections? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: I understand but don't know how to show you since it's wordpress content, and I have no styling...